# Java-Reading from a file to initalize an object with data conversion

Tags: java, file, object, bufferedreader

I have this file: "Test.txt" -> `1,cont,details,950.5,asd`

My Class is Auto, the constructor is `int, string, string, double, string`.

How can I read from this file and then initialize my object with the correct data conversion?

I think I need to use a comma splitter too.

```
    FileReader inFile2=null;
    BufferedReader outBuffer2=null;
    inFile2=new FileReader("Test.txt");
    outBuffer2 = new BufferedReader(inFile2);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line="";

    while((line = outBuffer2.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
        System.out.println(lines);
    }
    outBuffer2.close();
    inFile2.close();

    // 

    String[] splitTranzactie = lines.toArray(new String[]{});
    Auto t = new Auto(Int32(splitTranzactie[0]), splitTranzactie[1], splitTranzactie[2],
        ToDouble(splitTranzactie[3]), splitTranzactie[4]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First of all:

```
 String[] splitTranzactie = lines.toArray(new String[]{});
```

is going to just turn your list of lines into an array of lines. To split each line into its constituent parts you can use something like String.split(","). This will return an array of Strings. Note that if you expect any of the last values to be empty, i.e. ending in one or more commas then the returned array will be as long as the last value position it finds. i.e. if the line is `1,cont,details,,` you split will return an array of length 3 not 5. You should code defensively against this.

To convert a String to an int or double you can use `Integer.parseInt()` and `Double.parseInt()` respectively. Again you may want to consider coding defensively if the values may be anything other than numeric values as those two methods will throw an exception if they can't parse the input.

You should also place your `close()` methods in a finally block to ensure they are called, however as they are `AutoCloseable` you can avoid this altogether by using the try-with-resources syntax which will close the reader automatically.

```java
    try(Reader in = new Reader()) {
    }
```

A working example with all of the above (but without any defensive code) following your example may look something like the following:

```java
        List<Auto> autos = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt"))) {
            String line = null;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                autos.add(new Auto(
                        Integer.parseInt(values[0]),
                        values[1],
                        values[2],
                        Double.parseDouble(values[3]),
                        values[4]));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, in the end if i use in.Close(); this will close the FileReader too?

Comment: You don't need to. BufferedReader.close() calls close() on the underlying Reader.  The code above cleans up all the resources for you.

Answer (score 0):

For int you can use

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

Almost the same for the double

```
double b = Double.parseDouble(string);
```

But be aware that both can throw NumberFormatException if the string is not what it is meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

you can create stream from the lines then you can apply the

Function(ArrayList< String >,ArrayList< Auto >)

interface  to get data by defining custom behaviour through lambda function. To convert data to integer from String use Integer.parse(String) and for double data use Double.parse(string)

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 stream:

```
 try (Stream<String> fileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get("Test.txt"))) {
        fileStream.map(line -> line.split(",")).forEach(array -> {
            Auto auto = new Auto(Integer.parseInt(array[0]), array[1], array[2], Double.parseDouble(array[3]), array[4]);
        });
    }
```

You can collect the auto to list by:

```
    List<Auto> autoList;
    try (Stream<String> fileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get("Test.txt"))) {
        autoList = fileStream.map(line -> {
            String[] array = line.split(",");
            return new Auto(Integer.parseInt(array[0]), array[1], array[2], Double.parseDouble(array[3]), array[4]);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your current scheme, here one way I might carry out the task. The code also validates the data and places defaults if those validations fail.

```
public List<Auto> getAutoListFromFile(String filePath) {
    List<Auto> list = new ArrayList<>(); // Declare a List Interface
    Auto auto;  // Declare Auto
    // Open a file reader. Try With Resourses is used here so as to auto close reader.
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line = "";
        // Iterate through the file lines
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim(); // Trim lines of any unwanted leading or trailing whitespaces, tabs, etc.
            // Skip blank lines.
            if (line.equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(line); // Display file line to console (remove if desired).
            /* Split the current comma delimited file line into specific components.
               A regex is used here to cover all comma/space scenarios (if any). */
            String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}");
            // Establish the first Auto memeber value for the Auto class constructor. 
            int id = -1;  // default
            // Make sure it is an unsigned Integer value. RegEx is used here again.
            if (lineParts[0].matches("\\d+")) {
                id = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[0]);
            }
            // Establish the second Auto memeber value for the Auto class constructor.
            String cont = !lineParts[1].equals("") ? lineParts[1] : "N/A";  //Ternary Used
            // Establish the third Auto memeber value for the Auto class constructor.
            String details = !lineParts[2].equals("") ? lineParts[2] : "N/A";  //Ternary Used
            // Establish the fourth Auto memeber value for the Auto class constructor.
            double price = 0.0d;  //default
            // Make sure it is a signed or unsigned Integer or double value. RegEx is used here again.
            if (lineParts[3].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                price = Double.parseDouble(lineParts[3]);
            }
            // Establish the fifth Auto memeber value for the Auto class constructor.
            String asd = !lineParts[4].equals("") ? lineParts[4] : "N/A"; //Ternary Used
            auto = new Auto(id, cont, details, price, asd); // Create an instance of Auto
            list.add(auto); // Add Auto instance to List.
            // Go and read next line if one exists
        }   
    }
    // Handle Exceptions.
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("getAutoListFromFile() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("getAutoListFromFile() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list;  // Return the filled list.
}
```

And to use this method you might do:

```
List<Auto> list = getAutoListFromFile("Test.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations